# wordpress multisite not installing

Tags: multisite, installation

When trying to install multisite on my wordpress blog, I get a blank page on the 2nd step where I should get the options to choose from subdomain or sub directory. I've tried installing on several occasions and still the same problem persists. All plugins are deactivated. Help plsssss

Comment: [Turn on debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to get more information about *why* you're getting a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

A blank page usually indicate that you have some php error. You should look at your PHP error log file and try to fix the error if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

this does not work, there is not any related errors in the available logs.

I am still stucked in the second step where I should get the 2 radios telling me to choose between subdomains or subfolder config. You can find a print screen of the page here : http://screenpresso.com/=mRIld